# Best practices to deal with the lack of inheritance in Go

Tags: inheritance, go, modeling

I am about to start writing a new application and I was thinking about programming it in Go, which I have no experience with. As Go doesn't support inheritance how would I faithfully translate a domain like this into Go, while still being in accordance with the philosophy of Go?:

- A person has 2 legs and 2 arms and can walk.
- A musician is a person, has an instrument and can play it, has partitions and can read them. But nobody can be only a musician, as a musicien has and plays a specific instrument.
- A violonist is a musician that has a violon and can play the violon
- A pianist is a musician that has a piano and can play the piano.
- When a violonist/pianist is walking in the streets, everybody only sees him as a person.

Maybe we could reformulate the domain like this to remove any 'is a' relationships so that it would be translatable into Go:

- A violinist has a person part, a musician part, a violin and can play the violin
- The musician part of a violinist/pianist has partitions and can read them
- When a violinist/pianist is walking in the streets, everybody can only see his person part
- Etc

Would it be the best practice to model such a domain like this before translating into Go? Is it the way of thinking that the authors of Go want their users to have, when they decided to exclude inheritance in Go?

Comment: composition and interface will flatten the type hierarchy you d have created using inheritance. Its not excluded, its considered bad because it adds useless complexity. For what it worth, this might give you more to think around https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM1iUe6IofM

Comment: There is no concise answer to this question. It's just a different programming paradigm. You need to learn it if you want to use it. There's not any formula where OOP comes in one side, and a clean Go solution comes out the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go has just another point of view. You can think of objects and interfaces they match. It's closer to you second sentences:

> A violinist has a person part, a musician part, a violin and can play the violin

This is interface `Musician` - it describes any person which have method `Play()`

```
type Musician interface {
    Play()
}
```

For exapmple structure `Violinist` can have such a method:

```
type Violinist struct {}
func (v Violinist) Play() {}
```

Also `Pianist` can play:

```
type Pianist struct {}
func (v Pianist) Play() {}
```

They both match interface `Musician`. So you can have a `musician` variable and assign different musicians to it:

```
var musician Musician
musician = Violinist{}
musician.Play()
musician = Pianist{}
musician.Play()
```

Look how the same variable changes it's bahaviour. It's the same like Polyformism and not in OOP-way, but  Go-way.

> When a violinist/pianist is walking in the streets, everybody can only see his person part

The same way we may define a `Walker` interface - person who can walk a street and have appropriate method `Walk` for it:

```
type Walker interface {
    Walk()
}
```

It's a sort of duck-typing: in our life if a person can play, it can be taken to the ensemble. In Go terms if a person has method `Play()` it can be assigned to a musician type variable.

> Etc

Next you can make a combined interface embedding these both:

```
type WalkingMusician interface {
    Musician
    Walker
}
```

This describes a person which can play and walk at a moment.

```
var walkingMusician WalkingMusician
walkingMusician = walkingViolinist
walkingMusician.Walk()
walkingMusician.Play()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ai-h4VDUpj

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

So we use interfaces when we expect 2 types to have the same method, but which differs in implementation (like both violinist and pianist can play, but playing the violin isn't the same as playing the piano).

But if 2 types should have the same method which does the same thing for both (e.g. reading a partition is the same for both violinist and pianist), then we should use composition: violonist and pianist will both have a musician part and this musician part can read a partition.

Is that right?

Comment: I just extended your example to add a Solfege struct with a ReadPartition method and a WalkingPianist struct that can call the ReadPartition method of the Solfege struct. See: https://play.golang.org/p/VmpDnN9HX2.
I believe I now get the point thanks to your help. Then, I will mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 4):

It's not "the way of thinking that the authors of Go want their users to have"; Go does not have inheritance because it is not an object-oriented language, in much the same way C doesn't have inheritance.

It does have composition and interfaces, which are all you need to model what you've described: an object that "has a" other object should have a field of that type (composition), and an object that "can" perform some action can be modeled by an interface.

This question might be easier to answer if it described an actual programming problem rather than a metaphor, however; unless, of course, your application intends to model the limbs and instruments of various kinds of musicians.

Comment: Before I will ever try to solve an actual programming problem, I will make a pseudo application like the one described above, to see how it is to modelize something in Go, and if I can embrace the Go philosophy or not. I believe that the very first thing one needs to learn about a language is the vision of its authors. Without that, I will always fight against Go, trying to find workarounds to what appears to me to be limitation of the language.

Comment: If Go hasn't inheritance that's probably because this concept does not fit the vision of its authors and they were thinking of an alternate elegant way of achieving what could be achieved with inheritance. That's what I am trying to figure out at this point.

Comment: And as you can see in the answer from Eugene Lisitsky and my comments below, this metaphor was for me the right example to start with to enable me to understand the basics of go.